# how to send firebase push notification with big image using firebase console

Tags: push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-console

In unity based app Push Notification with title, message, big-image and also icon of the app.
how to send firebase push notification with big image using firebase console.

I am trying with custom data key -> value pair
image-> imageurl

but my device not display image. it displays only title and message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've looked around a lot through firebase's documentation and examples of firebase and big picture. It looks like the normal way to have firebase display a big picture push notification is through java code. You can also send custom data through your custom data key -> imageurl. But loading the imageurl would be handled through your code.

Firebase's unity plugin can not display a big picture push notification inside unity. You'd have to call java code triggered from Firebase.Messaging.FirebaseMessaging.MessageReceived event.